# How to insert NSMutableArray Contains object to Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I have some data, it contain in NSMutableArray, i have to add this array contain data to core data. one data normally i added to the core data i t working fine but how to multiple data. The data is present in my mutablearray

```
 _device = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DatabeaconBasket" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];


                     [_device setValue:@"12345" forKey:@"id"];
                     [_device setValue:@"27.995" forKey:@"latitude"];
NSError *error = nil;
                    if ([_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"data saved");
                        //[tableDataArray addObject:newDevice];
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"Error occured while saving");
                    }
```

i tried this code . i am new in using core data please help me

Comment: Do a for loop, and save once the loop is done (not after each creation)?

Comment: @Larme Thanks worked for me,
can u tell me how to search qq,ww,ee with thsese data i want o find one id in the coredata is it possible to do.

Comment: Look for fetch and predicate.